# absolute path for image file not working

Tags: php, image, file, path, absolute

```
echo '<img src="../../images/delete.png" id="aaa" />aaa&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';  (working fine)

//define( 'ROOT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) );  is in a file at root folder.
//i able to use this ROOT_DIR to include class files without any problem
//BUT, when I use it with photo image, it just not working!

echo '<img src="'.ROOT_DIR.'/images/delete.png" id="bbb" />bbb';
```

Guys, any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to work from the web server root, not the file system root.

If your main page is `/var/www/html/index.html` and your image is `/var/www/html/images/delete.png`, then your image href should be `/images/delete.png`.

Answer (score 3):

Probably because you are mixing directory path and URI. The directory where your script is located is different then it's URI in your website. You should define a `ROOT_URI` constant that would held the top URI of your application and use it.

```
echo '<img src="../../images/delete.png" id="aaa" />aaa&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';  (working fine)

//define( 'ROOT_URI', 'some/uri' );  is in a file at root URI.

echo '<img src="'.ROOT_URI.'/images/delete.png" id="bbb" />bbb';
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of using ROOT_DIR try `http://".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].'/images...`